# The Feasibility of Living Metal

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, xenobiology, metals

Recently I have been playing a lot of stellaris, “ a strategy game that allows you to control a alien species and advance your way through the galaxy”. In the game there is something called “Living Metal”, which the game description of it says that it shows characteristics usually seen in biological life forms, such as environmental stimulus and self-sustaining processes. The in game description of it is to vague, but what The point I assume it was trying to get across was that it Essentially is capable of self reproduction, either sexual or asexual ( most likely asexual ), and if it shows many characteristics shown in life forms, I would assume that it needs energy to keep itself alive.

This got me thinking:

1. What conditions would a planet or what environmental pressures be needed to give rise to “Living Metal”.

Another question I would like answered is:

2. If such thing could exist, could it be created artificially, and what scientific inventions could be created using it  ( this question doesn’t really need to be answered, but if you answer the first half of this question then it’ll really be of great help. )

Comment: Nanomachines, son.

Comment: Could you please give a better, more detailed definition? This is a bit too broad and too vague at the moment...

Comment: Hallmarks of a good question: 1. Explain WHAT you want/need. 2. Explain WHY you want/need it. 3. Try to describe what you are aiming to ACHIEVE with it.

Comment: *"Environmental stimulus and self-sustaining processes":* and how does an airliner not qualify? 1. It is made mostly of metal. 2. It is powered by a self-sustaining process combining air taken from the environment with fuel from internal reserves to produce mechanical thrust and electric power. 3. It is able to respond to external stimuli to maintain a set airspeed, altitude, and attitude.

Comment: @Mephistopheles, Stellaris has traditional nanomachine "gray goo", and it's not related to the "living metal" IIRC

Comment: @user28434 The metal is a porous "beehive" that the nano/micro machines build and maintain, that's the only way I could see it work.

Answer (score 1):

Metals<sup>1</sup> do not have the range of chemical reactivity to support biological processes efficiently.

It is hypothesized that, due to chemical similarities with carbon, that silicon can be the basis for an alternative biology.  In an incredibly carbon-poor world, life may evolve around silicon-chain molecules, just as life on Earth currently uses carbon-chain molecules.  However, this has never been observed. (And all of the sci-fi stories get it wrong: A silicon based life form will be no more rock-like or glass-like than us humans resemble a shambling mass of diamonds.)

Looking at the (Wikipedia article on) [the abundance of chemical elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements), we see that a very carbon-poor world that is also very silicon heavy is incredibly unlikely.  The reason being: Stars will always produce more carbon than they will produce silicon, and unless there is something actively separating elements in a nebula, any natural planet formation will always have more carbon than silicon.

It's possible that silicon-based amino acids and protein chains have formed in the past... However, because carbon is a smaller atom than silicon, its chemical bonds will be stronger than the chemical bonds of a similar silicon-based molecule, giving all carbon-based life an immediate advantage over silicon-based life.  Carbon based life simply doesn't have to spend as much energy constantly synthesizing the molecules essential for its life.

Thus, silicon-based life can not evolve in a carbon-rich environment.

Taking this further, it is possible, but extremely unlikely, for metals to form compounds that have interesting chemical qualities, just as carbon and silicon have interesting qualities... but the number of reactions are greatly reduced and, being heavier atoms than even silicon, they also suffer from the fact that the bonds are weaker still. Carbon will quickly take the place of any metal-based biological molecule.

Such a "living metal" life form would have to evolve in an environment completely devoid of carbon and silicon.  It would never evolve *naturally* on a rocky planet.  And, given the fact that metals can't participate in some chemical reactions than carbon can, I have serious reservations about even the most intelligent designer being able to artificially construct a biological creature based on any metal's chemistry.

This puts us firmly in the realm of scientific implausibility.

Still, putting on our sci-fi hats, what would happen if some living metal microbes were released into the environment?

Well, they might be toxic.  Don't lick them. Don't inhale deeply.

However, just as they *might* be toxic to you, *you are most definitely toxic to them.*  Again, your carbon is going to be breaking down and stealing their chemical bonds at a frantic pace... Even more frantically if it's in an oxygen rich environment.

Based on our current understanding of chemistry, any metal-based life forms that you might want to sit in the same room with will have to be electromechanical, rather than biological.

---

<sup>1</sup>Pedantic tangent: According to astronomers, every element other than hydrogen and helium are metals. Thus, I'm acknowledging that there are a wide range of things that can be considered a metal, and dismissing them all in favor of the subset of metallic substances that most people know about, such as gold, tin, silver, copper, iron, platinum, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, the short answer to your questions is that, as far as I know, we don’t know yet. In fact, we don’t know for certain how life first arose on earth—how the first clump of inanimate organic molecules twitched and became life. Evolutionary biologists are pretty sure it involved a primordial soup rich in organic matter and an energy source (probably oceanic geothermal vents and/or lightning). But because life arose exactly once and then proliferated, it’s hard to say what exactly sparked it first. And it’s just as hard to say what sort of environment could give rise to life that isn’t carbon-based, especially since we’ve never studied or even encountered it before.

As for the question of whether or not metallic life could exist, it all depends on how you define what is “alive” and “not alive,” and even biologists disagree on how to define life, because as soon as you list criteria, you encounter some exception to the rule—something that is obviously alive but doesn’t possess all of the criteria. Mules, for example, are obviously alive, but lack the ability to reproduce. Usually, something is considered to be alive when it exhibits most of these properties: when it can adapt to changes in the environment, has the ability to grow or change and develop over time, has the ability to maintain a stable internal state such as body temperature (homeostasis), is organized into one or more cells, has the ability to reproduce, and has the ability to respond to changes in the environment. The NASA definition, as proposed by Carl Sagan, is “a self-sustaining chemical system capable of Darwinian evolution.” This is obviously Earth-centered, though, and when it comes to alien life and the variety of chemistries and forms it could take, all bets are off the table.

Skeptics will point out that even silicon-based life seems unlikely, given that silicon can’t bond to as many other elements or form molecular chains as complex as carbon can. Metals entail the same problem, if not more so, but exobiology is a nascent field, and again, who knows what’s out there among the trillions of planets and moons in our galaxy alone?

In their excellent recent book “Imagined Life,” James Trefil and Michael Summers have a whole chapter devoted to the question you’re asking. In it, they survey recent research done by the chemist Lee Cronin, who is looking for nonorganic processes that can essentially produce a cell membrane using metals such as tungsten, vanadium, or molybdenum.

They also describe a hypothetical metallic exoplanet—a whole world that could be considered alive because of how its complex systems of magnetic and electric currents and fields interact at a level akin to the chemical processes at work in a biological carbon based organism.

Obviously such a world bears little resemblance to ours, and it’s unlikely that humans could even recognize metallic life forms as being alive. But that has more to do with our carbon chauvinism, as Carl Sagan called it, than with the debate over whether such things are actually alive.

Anyway, I recommend you check it out. It’s a great book.